# slre regex library fails to work for regex starting with (?i) for case-insensitive searching

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2013

I have a strange problem. I am looking for a light weight regex library to use with Visual Studio. Someone recommended me https://github.com/cesanta/slre; this library is all I need, and it is very light weight.

The problem is that it does not work under Visual Studio 2013. I compiled it with the following example but the printf statament is never reached.

```
static const char *str =
  "<img src=\"HTTPS://FOO.COM/x?b#c=tab1\"/> "
  "  <a href=\"http://cesanta.com\">some link</a>";

static const char *regex = "(?i)((https?://)[^\\s/'\"<>]+/?[^\\s'\"<>]*)";
struct slre_cap caps[2];
int i, j = 0, str_len = strlen(str);

while (j < str_len &&
       (i = slre_match(regex, str + j, str_len - j, caps, 2, 0)) > 0) {
  printf("Found URL: [%.*s]\n", caps[0].len, caps[0].ptr);
  j += i;
}
```

Could somebody take a look, or recommend me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: How about testing it with trivial patterns first ("a" matching "a")? A wild guess is that some of the regexp features you use  (like (?i) flag) are not implemented (or perhaps have another syntax) in slre.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko: agree about testing first with trivial patterns. About the features available it appears that `(?i)` is supported (written in the doc).

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: the above code is a copy/paste example from slre doc.

Comment: I give my tongue to the cat :)

Comment: yes it should work. but somone can enlighten me what is wrong ?

Comment: I suggest debugging through the code... It's a small piece of code after all, but it's too bad these guys decided that `foo`, `bar`, `baz` and `doh` are good function names ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in the `slre` library with case insensitive matching by starting your regex with `(?i)`. They have your example even in their unit tests but do not check if this test passes :)

Good news is that you can do case insensitive matching with a workaround by removing the `(?i)` part at the beginning of your regex and change the last argument in your call to `slre_match` to `SLRE_IGNORE_CASE` (or simply `1` as this is the value this constant is set to in `slre.h`) instead of plain `0`.

Therefore the correct usage of `slre_match` in your example is

```
slre_match(regex, str + j, str_len - j, caps, 2, SLRE_IGNORE_CASE)
```

and remove the `(?i)` part at the beginning of your regex.

Comment: thanks a lot bro, but I think i will write my own code after this experience

Comment: @opc0de: that is not necessarily the best lesson to learn from this.  Not all libraries are created equal.  Some have more testing than others.  Some have bugs that others don't.  Would you have got the functionality you need from SLRE more quickly by writing it yourself?  It seems unlikely.  But you need to do QA on libraries you choose to use.  It's unusual for an example to fail, but it can happen — you have proof of that.

Comment: @opc0de I think the best approach would be to eliminate this bug in the library and send a pull request :). That's a part of open source libraries

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in another answer (and as I suspected at the first glance), `(?i)` isn't supported by slre yet, even though it's mentioned in the documentation and used in the examples.

Passing `SLRE_IGNORE_CASE` explicitly is certainly an option, but you can also add support for `(?i)` in its simplest form, as it's documented: no support for `(?iiii)` or any other flags, just the fixed `(?i)` prefix.

My patch for `slre.c` is rather trivial. (Maybe it would make sense to submit it as a pull request to github).

```
diff --git a/slre.c b/slre.c
index 4a7fd89..d3c7672 100644
--- a/slre.c
+++ b/slre.c
@@ -429,5 +429,9 @@ int slre_match(const char *regexp, const char *s, int s_len,
   info.caps = caps;

   DBG(("========================> [%s] [%.*s]\n", regexp, s_len, s));
+  if (!strncmp("(?i)",regexp,4)) {
+    regexp+=4;
+    info.flags |= SLRE_IGNORE_CASE;
+  }
   return foo(regexp, (int) strlen(regexp), s, s_len, &info);
 }
```